# classic asp IIS 7.5 sql server performance

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, sql-server-native-client

We have been using this external program thats using classic asp, and sql server express 2008R2 on windows server 2008R2 running IIS 7.5

It has been running fine until the last month when almost each page is taking atleast 2 minutes to load. If i reboot the web server, everything works fine for the first few mins until it goes back to same old issues. 
It appears that the app is resetting some setting after 2 minutes and then its able to respond. I am not sure what setting that would be.

I tried to set up failed trace request, and found that it never finished or rather the log file never capture the error. (even after increasing the log file size. I tried this multiple times)

The program is using SQL server native client 10 to talk to sql server. I have played around with connection pooling, changing the app pool from classic to integrated and vice versa. It does not seem to be a db issue, as the activity monitor does not show too much consumption and sql server wait stat that i see is ASYNC_NETWORK_IO and PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT which relates to the fact on how the client is processing the results sent from the db server.

I am looking for suggestions on how to debug this issue. My guess has to be the way the connection from asp to sql server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things - 1) Do you have a back up copy of your code from a time when it was working without issues? If so you can use a program like WinMerge to compare and contrast the old code with the new code to track down coding issues (if that's where the problem lies). 2) Have you ruled out the holy hardware trinity (memory, disk, network)?

Comment: I have not really made any changes to the code. Whats interesting is the website has good response for some time when the web server is restarted and then the performance degrades..I m not sure why. Its as if some kind of locking is going on, but i cant find anything on the db server, however the IIS w3wp.exe process memory spikes up indicating IIS is doing a lot of work trying to do something...

Comment: I'd recommend going through the troubleshooting steps to first rule out the system you're using with perfmon then look under the hood at IIS.  You'd be surprised at how one little piece of code or even a character(s) in the code can cause something like this.